# awk to Transpose ChildIDs Column into Row

Tags: awk

Would like to transpose ChildID -2nd field ( i.e column to row against Desc/ParentID: row)

Tr_Input.txt

```
Desc,ParentID,ChildID,Location
mmmm,aa123aa,11,www
pppp,bb456bb,40,www
mmmm,aa123aa,33,www
pppp,bb456bb,20,www
xxxx,cc789cc,88,www
mmmm,aa123aa,22,www
pppp,bb456bb,60,www
mmmm,aa123aa,44,www
xxxx,cc789cc,88,www
```

The below command is working fine when we consider ParentID,ChildID's  only:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} {a[$2]=a[$2] FS $3} END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i]} }' Tr_Input.txt
```

Output:

```
ParentID,ChildID's 
,,
aa123aa,,11,33,22,44
cc789cc,,88,88
bb456bb,,40,20,60
```

While trying  to add one more field like "Desc,ParentID"wise ChildID , got struck, Have tried below command and un-successful:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} {a[$1]=a[$1] FS a[$2] FS $3} END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i]} }' Tr_Input.txt
```

Output

```
,,,
aa123aa,
cc789cc,
mmmm,,,11,,33,,22,,44
pppp,,,40,,20,,60
xxxx,,,88,,88
bb456bb,
```

Desired Output:

```
Desc,ParentID,ChildID's
mmmm,aa123aa,11,33,22,44
xxxx,cc789cc,88,88
pppp,bb456bb,40,20,60
```

Looking for your suggestions !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR > 1 {desc[$2]=$1; child[$2] = child[$2] OFS $3} 
    END {
        print "Desc,ParentID,ChildID'\''s"
        for (parent in desc)
            print desc[parent] OFS parent child[parent]
    }
' filename
```

```
Desc,ParentID,ChildID's
mmmm,aa123aa,11,33,22,44
xxxx,cc789cc,88,88
pppp,bb456bb,40,20,60
```

The "child" array is where the childID's are actually accumulated. I was tempted to code this in perl because of the more flexible data structures, but you wanted awk.